# xslt position always returns 1

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Envelopes>
        <xsl:variable name="var1" select="ExtObj:GetXml()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$var1/*"/>
    </Envelopes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='xyz/abc'>
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Now `$var1` has elements which matches the second template, but the `$pos` always is set at 1. How can I get the position of the match?

Comment: Yes, because your var $pos is set only one time. And it is outside any other template, therefore is set only for the first element. XSLT vars cannot change their value once they are set (so they behave more like constants), but even if they did, your code would be executed for each xyz/abc element and in the end the value of $pos would be always the last element. Since the value cannot be changed, is set to the first element -that is 1- and is not changed on each iteration. Why don't you just use position() inside the template that handles the xyz/abc elements?

Comment: What _exactly_ is the content of `var1`?  If `var1` is a set of nodes one of which is an `xyz` element, and that `xyz` has an `abc` child, then yes I agree it should do what you expect.  But if `var1` is a document root node or fragment, and `$var1/*` is therefore a set of one or more `xyz` elements then you're relying on the implicit default template matching `xyz` and doing `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, in which case the `position()` will be the position of the `abc` within its parent's list of child nodes, not within `$var1`.

Comment: The fix in this case would of course be to do `<xsl:apply-templates select="$var1/*/*" />` to pick out all the `abc` elements in one select.

Comment: A loop may be a better idea rather than sending in a template each time that will always be one since it is the first position of this match.

Comment: @JBKing whether you use a `for-each` or an `apply-templates` the principle is the same - `position()` gives you the position of the current node within the set of nodes that the `for-each` or `apply-templates` selected. If you use the right `select` expression then you'll get the right `position()`

Comment: @chris, I think you have misread the code. The call to position() IS inside the template that handles the xyz/abc elements.

Comment: @IanRoberts: could you put that in an answer, so this question can get off the Unanswered list?

Comment: @MichaelKay No, that template is only creating the $pos variable. It seems he attempted to create $pos in order to somehow use it outside that template later - on some other template I guess. That is what I meant.

Comment: @chris perhaps you're right. He'd removed all references to $pos from his code, so we both made guesses about where the references were before he removed them, and guessed differently.

Comment: Sorry everybody for keeping you guessing. Was gone for the past 16 hrs or so. Anyway, @MichaelKay you guessed it right.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks, your suggestion solved the problem. Would be glad to accept your suggestion as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `position()` function is inherently context-sensitive - it gives you the position of the current node within the set of nodes selected by the `apply-templates` that caused this template to fire.  So it depends on *exactly* what the `$var1` variable contains.  If `$var1` is a node set containing `xyz` elements, each of which has a single `abc` child, then `$var1/*` will select all the `abc` elements in one go:

```
<xyz>        <!-- $var1    -->
  <abc/>     <!-- $var1/*  -->
</xyz>
<xyz>        <!-- $var1    -->
  <abc/>     <!-- $var1/*  -->
</xyz>
```

(the whitespace text nodes and comments are for clarification only, assume the real XML tree contains only the element nodes) and you'll get the `position()` values you expect.

But if `$var1` is a single root node in the XPath data model (e.g. a document fragment) that has the `xyz` elements as its children, then `$var1/*` will select the `xyz` elements, not the `abc` ones.

```
             <!-- $var1  (the root node)  -->
<xyz>        <!-- $var1/*                 -->
  <abc/>
</xyz>
<xyz>        <!-- $var1/*                 -->
  <abc/>
</xyz>
```

Now when you apply templates to these the implicit default template will match them, and for each one it will recursively call `apply-templates` on that node's children (the single `abc` element).  So now `position()` will give you the position of the `abc` within the set of its parent's children, which will always be 1.

If this *is* what's happening, then the easiest fix is to say

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$var1/*/*"/>
```

to select all the `abc` elements in one go.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to use `<xsl:for-each ...>`. That will set position() correctly.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$var/xyz/abc">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: See the comments on the question - it makes no difference whether you use `apply-templates` or `for-each`, what matters is getting the `select` expression right.

Comment: In theory. I have experienced different behavior in corner cases. Until the asker tries, this is a valid answer from my POV.

Comment: (and BTW, it's `for-each`, not `forEach`)